# bash: strip a line of some patterns

Tags: regex, bash, parsing

I am trying to process the following string in a bash script:

```
002d2fc1203cd4e55ace589c921387cd,l=340x125,f=151x125,i=230x365
```

The line can contain any number of size description (i=230x365, x=330x665, etc)

The purpose is to get this output:

```
002d2fc1203cd4e55ace589c921387cd,l,f,i
```

I have tried to play with sed and grep to no avail, the result has to be on a single line since I am processing many such lines at a time, so each output line should respect the above pattern.

Comment: You just want to remove all `=###x###` from the line? Isn't that a simple `sed` substitution?

Comment: Apprently it is indeed a sed substitution, but not _that_ simple to me at least (See the accepted answer).

Comment: The only thing simpler than that is a substitution with no special regular expression operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this line:

```
sed 's/=[^,]*//g'
```

test

```
kent$  echo "002d2fc1203cd4e55ace589c921387cd,l=340x125,f=151x125,i=230x365"|sed 's/=[^,]*//g'
002d2fc1203cd4e55ace589c921387cd,l,f,i
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Although I can't seem to get the logic behind it, could you please explain what the pattern means?

Comment: @Aki the sed line removes each part of `=.....(before comma)` from input string.

Comment: +1 this is much simpler than awk.